# .gitignore for Lua projects

Tags: git, lua, gitignore

I've noticed that GitHub [does not have a .gitignore template](https://github.com/github/gitignore) for Lua projects.

Are there any specific files/file extensions which should be excluded by default from source control for a Lua project? I don't know enough about the Lua build/test/deploy cycle to know for myself yet.

Comment: Shouldn't you have a "Lua build/test/deploy cycle" functioning *before* asking that question?

Comment: Eh? I have a build/test/deploy cycle functioning. But what are the chances that my first build/test/deploy cycle will catch every edge case? It didn't involve `luac`, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`luac`, by default, writes its output to `luac.out`. Other than that, it would depend on any build system that you use for additional output such as from `luadoc`.

Comment: Thanks Tom, marking as the correct answer as you came up with a Lua file worth .gitignoring!

Answer (score 3):

There aren't really any such files for Lua.  Contrast that with Python which writes .pyc and .pyo files that you usually don't want to check in; Lua produces no such files usually.

Comment: Cheers John, that's reassuring to know.